# Avoiding user's input in input type for jsp

Tags: html, jsp

The code shown below will prevent the user from entering any value in input type. Is there a way the box can be hidden in this case.

```
<input id="vendor" name="vendor" type="text" 
       class="txtsmall2"  value="<%=variable%>" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: So you don't want to display this input textbox at all ?

Comment: I want to display it without a box if possible

Comment: @Amit.rk3 can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
<input id="vendor" name="vendor" type="hidden" 
       value="<%=variable%>" /><span class="txtsmall2"><%=variable%></span>
```

Where you have a hidden input followed by a visible text element that is not an input but has the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Changing type to hidden would hide the input field.

```
<input id="vendor" name="vendor" type="hidden" 
    class="txtsmall2"  value="<%=variable%>" readonly="readonly"/>
```

As OP mentioned in a comment, if want to show the text content but not the borders, try:

```
<input style="border:0" "id="vendor" name="vendor" type="text" 
    class="txtsmall2"  value="abc" readonly="readonly"/>
```

CSS can be in-line, internal, or external sheet. I kept it simple here.

Comment: Yes. Did you mean that show the text content with being formatted as a text box? It looked like you wanted to completely hide it.

Comment: In case there is no result completely hide it and when there is some result box should not be there only text. Don't know if that is possible though.

Comment: Made an edit. If that works, I will delete the previous code. Let me know.